# How can I have multiple kibana URLs for each server while my ELK is setup on the same centralised machine?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, filebeat

I am using ELK stack with filebeat. filebeat is sending logs from multiple servers and logstash is collecting logs and sending them to Elastic search , then it is sending it to kibana. But I am looking for a solution where I can setup Multiple kibana URLs for each server. My Elk is setup on the same master machine. How it is possible to create multiple kibana urls for the same machine?

Comment: why you need multipul URLs of kibana ? do you mean seperate dashboard for each machine ?

Comment: Thank you so much for reply

 yes, separate dashboard for each machine. it's like I want a particular department to see only particular machine logs not all. like single dashboard is showing all logs.

Comment: ok got it !! for this you not required sepertae URL but you need to create seperate space in Kibana and you can give access to each departments. You can read more about [space](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/xpack-spaces.html) here.

Comment: But I want to restrict the logs also people see. In the spaces, I am unable to find a feature like this.

Comment: you want to resrtict log based on server right ?

Comment: yes. I am trying to find the kibana privileges but unable to find that on kibana dashboard.

Comment: You need to provide Kibana query while creating dashboard on top of the search box so it will show only specific server details in dashboard. like this you can create dashboard for each server and each dashboard you can configured to each dpartment space.